# Is always possible to define a numerical value using subscript?

Tags: variable-definitions, numerical-value, subscript

In this code I defined some values using subscripts and it is not the first time I did this but strangely the code execution crashes. To follow the code.

```
   Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = 6000;
Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] = 9810;
Subscript[p, M] = 0.038*9.81/10^-2;
s = {Subscript[p, A], Subscript[p, B], Subscript[p, C]} /. 
   Solve[{Subscript[p, C]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] == 
      Subscript[p, M]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] - 5, 
     Subscript[p, B]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] == 
      Subscript[p, M]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] + 1, 
     Subscript[p, A]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] == 
      Subscript[p, B]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] + 
       6}, {Subscript[p, A], Subscript[p, B], Subscript[p, C]}];
Subscript[p, A] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 1];
Subscript[p, B] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 2];
Subscript[p, C] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 3];
A = {Subscript[p, A]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 0};
B = {Subscript[p, B]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 6};
C = {Subscript[p, C]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 12};
Graphics[Line[{A, B, C}], Axes -> True]
```

So where is the mistake? Pheraps is not always possible to define a numerical value using subscript?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131772/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-maria-di-mauro-is-always-possible-to-define-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a fresh kernel:

```
Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = 6000;
Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] = 9810;
Subscript[p, M] = 0.038*9.81/10^-2;

s = {Subscript[p, A], Subscript[p, B], Subscript[p, C]} /. 
  Solve[{Subscript[p, C]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] == 
     Subscript[p, M]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] - 5, 
    Subscript[p, B]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] ==
     Subscript[p, M]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] + 1, 
    Subscript[p, A]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] == 
     Subscript[p, B]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] + 
      6}, {Subscript[p, A], Subscript[p, B], Subscript[p, C]}]

Subscript[p, A] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 1];
Subscript[p, B] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 2];
Subscript[p, C] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 3];
aa = {Subscript[p, A]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 0};
bb = {Subscript[p, A]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 6};
cc = {Subscript[p, C]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 12};
Graphics[Line[{aa, bb, cc}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT using lowercase subscripts**

Using a fresh kernel:

```
Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = 6000;
Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] = 9810;
Subscript[p, m] = 0.038*9.81/10^-2;

s = {Subscript[p, a], Subscript[p, b], Subscript[p, c]} /. 
  Solve[{Subscript[p, c]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] == 
     Subscript[p, m]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] - 5, 
    Subscript[p, b]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] ==
     Subscript[p, m]/Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] + 1, 
    Subscript[p, a]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] == 
     Subscript[p, b]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O] + 
      6}, {Subscript[p, a], Subscript[p, b], Subscript[p, c]}]

Subscript[p, a] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 1];
Subscript[p, b] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 2];
Subscript[p, c] = Extract[Extract[s, 1], 3];
aa = {Subscript[p, a]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 0};
bb = {Subscript[p, b]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 6};
cc = {Subscript[p, c]/Subscript[\[Gamma], Subscript[H, 2] O], 12};
Graphics[Line[{aa, bb, cc}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The problem is that `pA`, `PB` etc are being used later on and you need to clear these before `Solve`. Starting with a fresh kernel the following can be evaluated any number of times. There are **no subscripts**, and **no uppercase starting symbols** either but you can experiment with variations yourself.

```
g1 = 6000;
gH20 = 9810;
pM = 0.038*9.81/10^-2;
```

Look at the color of the variables, that is a good sign that `Solve` recognizes these as variables.

```
Clear[s, pA, pB, pC];
s = {pA, pB, pC} /. First@Solve[{pC/g1 == pM/g1 - 5, pB/g1 ==
      pM/g1 + 1, pA/gH20 == pB/gH20 + 6}, {pA, pB, pC}]

pA = s[[1]]
pB = s[[2]];
pC = s[[3]];
aa = {pA/gH20, 0};
bb = {pB/gH20, 6};
cc = {pC/gH20, 12};
Graphics[Line[{aa, bb, cc}], Axes -> True]
```

I have made minor improvements to avoid a double `Extract`. The picture doesn't change from the second one.